# Use regular expression to find a character in a string and compare to another

Tags: ruby, regex

This is what I set up:

```
n = 1
/([1-99])/.match("company1") == n.to_s # => false
```

How can I compare `/([1-99])/.match("company1")` to `n` so that I get `true`?

Comment: note that `[1-99]` does not match numbers 1 to 99

Comment: You might want `\d{1,2}`

Comment: Do you need a regex? I'd use `'company1'.include?(n.to_s)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access the matched text inside `[MatchData][1]`, and you also need to adjust your regex to `[1-9][0-9]?` to match numbers from `1` till `99`:

> `MatchData` is the type of the special variable `$~`, and is the type of
>   the object returned by **`Regexp#match`** and `Regexp.last_match`. It
>   encapsulates all the results of a pattern match, results normally
>   accessed through the special variables `$&`, `$'`, `` $` ``, `$1`, `$2`, and so on.

So, use

```
puts /[1-9][0-9]?/.match("company1")[0] == n.to_s
```

See [demo](https://ideone.com/C7LtWc)

If you need to match whole word numbers, use `\b`: `/\b[1-9][0-9]?\b/`

Comment: It might be of interest that you can also get the expected result using [`/[1-9][0-9]?/.match("company1").to_s == n.to_s`](https://ideone.com/xBXYY3) because `to_s` will also expose the whole matched text.

Comment: Why is it that when the input is for example params[:invest_with]="user", I get the error>> /(company)\w/.match(params[:invest_with])[0]==params[:invest_with]
!! #<NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass>

Comment: Looks like you are using Action Controller. Check using `params = ActionController::Parameters.new(invest_with: 'company1')` before solves the issue. If yes, perform a nil check before running a regex on the param.

Comment: When I remove the [0] at the end I no longer get the error. However if params is equal to company# it also returns false without the [0]

Comment: Right, you get no result since there is no number. `[0-9]` requires at least 1 digit in the input string to return a non-nil result.